# ExpressJS callback functionality - correct implementation

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, express

So I have following scenario -

I have a post request for creating invoices.

I send following `.json` to the request:

```
{
  invoice: {
    client_id: 1,
    status: 'Open'
  },
  invoice_products: [
    {
      product_id: 1,
      quantity: 2
    },
    {
      product_id: 3,
      quantity: 55
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm first validating the data in the back-end, afterwards I follow these steps -

1) I'm doing a for loop on `invoice_products` and try to read the price from database for each product. It looks something like this -

```
// Let's retrieve price for the invoice
let price = 0;
for (let invoice_product_nr = 0; invoice_product_nr < req.body.invoice_products.length; invoice_product_nr++) {
    products.getById(req, req.body.invoice_products[invoice_product_nr].product_id, next);
    console.log(req.productData);
    price += req.productData.data.price;
}
```

and my `products.getById()` function looks like this -

```
function getById(req, id, next) {
    products.getOne(id)
        .then((data) => {
            // Check if product exists
            if (data === undefined) {
                const message = {
                    errors: response.errors.general.notFound
                };
                next();
            }

            // Everything is fine - return products data
            const message = {
                success: response.success.general.dataReturned,
                data
            };

            req.productData = message;

            next();

        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
            // Unexpected error happened, return error message.
            next();
        });
}
```

First issue here is that it doesn't have `req.productData` set, when it returns from the `getById` function, how could I possibly fix this?

2) Afterwards, I'm doing an insert to database using passed invoice data -

```
// Let's insert invoice in database
invoices.insert(invoice)
    .then((result) => {
        // Let's insert invoice products
        for (let invoice_product_nr = 0; invoice_product_nr < req.body.invoice_products.length; invoice_product_nr++) {
            let invoice_product = {
                invoice_id: result[0],
                product_id: req.body.invoice_products[invoice_product_nr].product_id,
                quantity: req.body.invoice_products[invoice_product_nr].quantity
            };
            invoice_products.insert(invoice_product)
                .then(() => {
                    next();
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.log(error);
                    // There is an internal error in database
                    return response.reportMessage(500, undefined, res);
                });
        }

        // invoice has been added, notify user
        const message = {
            success: response.success.general.dataAdded,
        };
        return response.reportMessage(201, message, res);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
        // There is an internal error in database
        return response.reportMessage(500, undefined, res);
    });
```

Here the issue is that I don't like the for loop with the insert statemnets, I plan to switch it to knex batch request (your suggestions?), the second issue here is that `response.reportMessage` does `res.send()`, and I get `headers already sent` errors.

Cheers!

Comment: You should use callback chain... node is async... for example... put `price += req.productData.data.price;` into `getById()` success ... etc.

Comment: okay, but then I would have to change it from void to return method, which would probably cause issues, because I want to switch those next() with res.send(xxx, message), where xxx is status code and message is according message. And this would cause issue nr.2, which I'm experiencing in insert statement.